# Can Blender addons execute Shell commands on Linux?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, command-line, linux

I'd make an addon that would use several external command line programs to process output images. Is this possible?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie so the answer is "yes"..... Executing Shell commands on any system could pose serious security problem, esp when the users do not know what those commands really do behind the curtain. This is just my guess, but I worry about it.

Comment: @BlenderLake, what exactly is the "serious security problem"? And why is it relevant if the users know what those commands do? Any third party Blender add-on is already a serious security risk anyway if you care about that. But how does using subprocess in an add-on change anything about security?

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys From this post, what I learnt is that I should buy or use any Blender addon only if it is absolutely necessary, otherwise my computer may be hacked very soon.

Comment: Add-ons run on the machine, so from security point of view, they are pretty much as much risk, as you get. I have never seen any malicious Blender add-ons though. My point is that your comment about executing shell commands and security makes no sense at all. I formed it as a question, because maybe you know something I don't. Do you? What difference does it make if a Python script already running on your system executes other commands? How is it a security risk? The way I see it, that's simply incorrect.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys In almost all cases, I (as the user) do not fully understand what those commands do. Therefore, if the Python script is written by the Blender Foundation, then I trust its safety. If it is written by other third parties, then I worry about the safety of my computer. For example, an addon named "Auto-Rig Pro" may be suspicious. On the following page, if you click the link " Mike (free)", then my FireFox stop downloading the ZIP file by citing "potential security risk": https://blendermarket.com/products/auto-rig-pro?num=4&src=popular

Comment: There is no additional security risk if an add-on runs shell commands. Add-ons can be malicious with Python alone, or they could launch other software that might be malicious. It's good to be mindful of that, however, this is not something that really happens a lot. Blender add-ons are just Python scripts, you can simply open any Blender add-on in a text editor and read its code to know what it does and how it works exactly. It is unlikely the creators of the add-on you link to could find a way to benefit from any sort of malicious code more than they already do from having a good product.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys In order to be malicious, addon has to communicate with the operation system. I don't know how to successfully achieve this communication if executing Shell commands is blocked. I also don't know how it launches other malicious software if accessing to Shell is forbidden. BTW, even if I spend a lot of time to read its code in a text editor, I still don't know if I am safe after the next update for the addon. Some addon can even directly connect to Internet behind the door during the update, such as the addon called "Hair Tool": https://bartoszstyperek.gumroad.com/l/hairtool

Comment: @BlenderLake, it is better to start a discussion about that somewhere else. Blenderartists.org forums maybe?.. You have to trust the source of any add-on in any case. Add-ons can do anything you can do with [Python](https://www.python.org/). If an add-on is malicious, it doesn't need shell commands to do harm and has the same access to the system as Blender or any processes that Blender can start. For example it can access the internet anyway. We have drifted off-topic and are not using comments for intended purpose so we should not carry it on here.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thank you for this meaningful conversation! In the future, I might ask in Blenderartists.org. But not now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you are running Blender on Linux, you can execute [shell commands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-shell-commands-in-linux/) in your Blender addon using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. In this example I pipe the commands [`sed`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/) and [`awk`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/) to replace the string `Hello World` with `Yes? Hello Blender!`:

```
import bpy
import subprocess

command = 'echo \'Hello World!\' | sed \'s/World/Blender/\' | awk \'{print "Yes? ", $0}\''
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
rc = result.returncode
print("return code:", rc)
output = result.stdout.strip() if rc == 0 else result.stderr.strip()
bpy.context.area.type = 'CONSOLE'
bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(text=output)
```

If you are running Blender on Windows, you can try this script:

```
import bpy
import subprocess

command = [
    "powershell.exe",
    "-Command",
    "$output = 'Hello World!' -replace 'World', 'Blender'; Write-Output $output"
]

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
rc = result.returncode
print("return code:", rc)
output = result.stdout.strip() if rc == 0 else result.stderr.strip()
bpy.context.area.type = 'CONSOLE'
bpy.ops.console.scrollback_append(text=output)
```